# Como formatar um campo com ASP.NET WebForms C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, formatação

Preciso formatar o TextBox `<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtValor" MaxLength="20"></asp:TextBox` e estou com muita dificuldade, primeiramente essa grid é aberta em um modal, ou seja, quando crio a pagina principal eu não consigo pegar o controle pelo javascript e colocar a mascara, pois esses controles ainda não foram inicializados.

Preciso realizar essa formatação apenas quando abrir esse modal e carregar esta grid, como posso realizar essa formatação para campo decimal?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upnVincGridFuncionarios" RenderMode="Inline" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gdvVincFuncionarios" Width="100%" OnRowDataBound="gdvVincFuncionarios_RowDataBound">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNameHead" Text='Nome'></asp:Label>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNameEmployee" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Msisdn" HeaderText="Celular" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Cpf" HeaderText="CPF" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="NumRegistration" HeaderText="Matrícula" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CostCenter" HeaderText="Centro de Custo" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />                        
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                             <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblValorHead" Text='Valor'></asp:Label>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <span style="display: none">
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblVincIdEm" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IdEm") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </span>     
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtValor" MaxLength="20"></asp:TextBox>                           
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode deixar no TextBox a propriedade `onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"` e no seu arquivo de javascript (ou mesmo em tela) a seguinte função:

```
function isNumberKey(evt)
{
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
        && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
         return false;

    return true;
}
```

Com isso, independente da mascara, sempre que uma tecla for pressionada no textbox o evento será chamado e caso não seja número será interrompido.